# Matlab find does not work with high dimensional array?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, matrix-indexing

say 
A = rand(2,2,2);
[a,b,c] = find(A == A(1,2,2))

I got
a=1
b=4
c=1

what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
[a,b,c] = ind2sub(size(A), find(A==A(1,2,2)))
```

Source: [find](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/find.html), [ind2sub](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ind2sub.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use equality `==` instead of assignment operator `=`.

```
A = rand(2,2,2); [a,b,c] = find(A == A(1,2,2))
```

See documentation for [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/find.html). output arguments are not for all directions, only rows and columns. It seems MATLAB concatenate the 3rd direction along the 2nd and returns 4th column. The last argument equals 1 because you have only one match.

Answer (score 0):

The outputs from the [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) function are two sets of indices (`a` and `b`) and the values at those indices (`c`). For matrices greater than 2 dimensions, the second index will be a [*linear* index](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#f1-85511).

In your example, you create a logical array when you do `A == A(1,2,2)`. This logical array, which has a value of `1` (i.e. `true`) at index `(1,2,2)`, is passed to the [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) function. The position of this non-zero value is in the first row of the matrix (output `a = 1`) and the fourth linear index within the remaining dimensions (output `b = 4`). The non-zero value of `1` is output for `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Find only works as you're trying to apply it for 2 dimensional arrays.

There are a few functions available over at Matlab Central that will do n-dimensional arrays.